# Armature bug: keyframes are "ineffective"

Tags: armature, keyframes

I downloaded a simple forearm rig from the internet in hopes of making some weapon animations. Alas, when I keyframe the rig, there is a stupid bug that stops me from effectively doing anything.

This is the default state, and it looks weird:
[image]

So, I go to the next frame, correct it, and make a keyframe:
[image]

I go back a frame and then return to my keyframe. Lo and behold... nothing.
[image]

Am I doing something wrong? I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

On the timeline panel try setting active keying set to "Whole Character Selected bones only".
See if that fixes the problem.
Also .blend would be nice to see if there's anything else I'm missing from the pictures.

[image: timeline]